# Calling the initial class from inside an object C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a Windows Form app in C#, I'm enforcing password protection.
I'm sorry for the poor title and explanation, as you can tell I'm an amateur.

The form that loads upon login is a class that is called from within `Program.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace POS
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]

        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Login());
        }
    }
}
```

The class is simply called Login. Once the user has successfully authenticated, I create a new object of a class, hide the Login form and open a new class.

```
namespace POS
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        RiverbankTeaRooms main = new RiverbankTeaRooms();
        private void Enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool found = false;
            try
            {
                // Search through database through dr[1] (Table 2) for matching string.
                foreach (DataRow dr in dra)
                {
                    if (dr[1].ToString() == Code.Text)
                    {
                        found = true;

                        // Open main form.
                        main.SignedIn = true;
                        main.Show();
                        this.Hide();
                        break;
                     }
                }
                if (found == false)
                {
                    // Incorrect password.

                    Code.Text = "Incor";
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // Error, most likely with Database.
                Code.Text = "Error";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine... To open the program and authenticate the user however I wish to be able to logout and open the Login form again from within the `RiverbankTeaRooms` class. I don't know how I'd be able to re-open the form Login again, as it has only been hidden, but I can't figure out how to do `Login.Show();`
I can't create a new instance of login inside the main form, because the `RiverbankTeaRooms` form won't be able to close.

This is driving me crazy, and sorry for the poor explanation!

Comment: I'd invert the logic, so that you call Application.Run(new RiverbankTeaRooms()), and hide on start up, and show login instead.

Comment: I don't mean to be a jerk, but if you are writing a production POS system and don't have someone senior on your team you are in WAY over your head.

Comment: This is just a simple computer project, it's simply for an exam. I'm only in A2.

I also tried the inverted logic, I don't remember how I did it, but somehow I thought it'd be a better idea to use the login form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to change the flow of the program.

Instead of showing the `RiverbankTeaRooms` from the `Login` on success, test the login result in your `Program.Main` and then show the `RiverbankTeaRooms` or any error message.

Add the following to Login :

```
    public bool Success { get; private set; }

    public static bool Authenticate()
    {
        var login = new Login();
        login.ShowDialog();

        return login.Success;
    }
```

And update your Enter_Click :

```
    private void Enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Search through database through dr[1] (Table 2) for matching string.
            foreach (DataRow dr in dra)
            {
                if (dr[1].ToString() == Code.Text)
                {
                    Success = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!Success)
            {
                // Incorrect password.
                Code.Text = "Incor";
            }
            else
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Error, most likely with Database.
            Code.Text = "Error";
        }
    }
}
```

And just use the Authenticate method :

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new RiverbankTeaRooms() { SignedIn = Login.Authenticate() });
}
```

If you need to authenticate again inside the `RiverbankTeaRooms`, you can do it like this :

```
if (Login.Authenticate())
{
    // do stuff...
}
else
{
    // show error, or stop the user
}
```

Comment: That's a great idea! Could you give me an example of how that would work though. I've never done anything like that.

Comment: I've added an example for you.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much, wish I could up vote you

Comment: Again, this was a perfect solution, can close the Login form now, instead of hiding it! Wish I could buy you a beer :D

Answer (score 2):

To answer the titular question, simply pass the `Login` instance to the `RiverbankTeaRooms` object:

```
RiverbankTeaRooms main = new RiverbankTeaRooms(this);

//In other form
Login myPrivateLoginReference;
public RiverBanksTeaRoom(Login loginForm)
{
   myPrivateLoginReference = loginForm;
}
```

For your specific case, there are other approaches, such as raising an event from `main` that would also work:

```
main.ShowLoginRequested += ShowLogin;

void ShowLogin()
{
   this.Show();
}
```

As an aside, please **never** store passwords as plaintext in a database, as it appears you are doing, you should always be comparing against a hash.

Comment: @StevenChorkley Added sample constructor that accepts a login object